# Nuget packaging in VS2017 csproj project

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, visual-studio-2017, csproj

I have following project structure with 3 Nuget dependencies:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>net45;net46</TargetFrameworks>
    ...
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit" Version="3.9.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Selenium.WebDriver" Version="3.7.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="SpecFlow.CustomPlugin" Version="2.2.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

It's really cool that VS2017 allows creating NuGet packages out of the box.

But what can do if I want to include custom NuGet references and don't wanna include references I use now?

```
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    ...
    <dependencies>
      <dependency id="SpecFlow" version="2.2.0" />
      <dependency id="NUnit" version="3.0.0" />
      <dependency id="Autofac" version="[3.3.0,3.5.2]" />
      <dependency id="Autofac.Configuration" version="[3.3.0]" />
      <dependency id="Selenium.WebDriver" version="3.0.0" />
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

I this case I need to have **Autofac** with my lib but I don't need it to build my lib. 
Or I don't need **SpecFlow.CustomPlugin** with all dependencies in project which will use my lib but it needs have one to build itself.

I think there is a way to include NuSpec file path to new csproj but I think all csproj **PropertyGroup** fields won't be used.

Any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use ExcludeAsset property following official documentation

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files

I modified the exemple in doc to match with your needs.
You can change the `ExcludeAssets` property if my change is not correct.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <!-- ... -->

    <PackageReference Include="Contoso.Utility.UsefulStuff" Version="3.6.0">
        <ExcludeAssets>build</ExcludeAssets>

    </PackageReference>

    <!-- ... -->
</ItemGroup>
```

**EDIT :**

I think you can try something like :

```
<PackageReference Include="Autofac" Version="3.5.2">
        <ExcludeAssets>build</ExcludeAssets>
  </PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="Autofac.Configuration" Version="3.3.0">
        <ExcludeAssets>build</ExcludeAssets>
  </PackageReference>
```

If I well understand the documentation, this will exclude **Props and targets in the build folder** that are used to create by nuget package to create the dependencies

Comment: Thanks for the link - still haven't figured out how to deal with it. Can you please post a config sample from my code when you have time? Thanks